# Get parent of clicked tag inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've an iframe that contain an HTML page.Now I want to get class of the parent item that clicked.
this is my ifram:

```
<iframe src="//example.com" id="frame" ></iframe>
```

this is css:

```
#frame{  width:380px;  height:420px;}
```

this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
  var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
  $(innerDoc).on('click', function(e) {
    var thisID = ((e.target).id);
    alert(thisID);
    alert(innerDoc.getElementById(thisID));


    $(thisID).click(function() {
      var Allclassnames = $(thisID).parent();
      console.log(Allclassnames);
    });
  });
});
```

but it return the item was clicked only.how to fix it?

Demo:[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/talebihamid/821ohtev/2/)

`NOTE`:these are in a same domain.maybe below `DEMO` not worked for this reason.but I'm sure that my HTML is inside of the same domain with my web site.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add sandbox attributes to the iframe

```
<iframe src="/example.html" id="frame" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Change the script to

```
<script>
$('#frame').load(function() {
  $('#frame').contents().on('click', function(e) {  
    var thisID = ((e.target).id);
    alert(thisID); 
    alert($('#'+thisID,this));
      $('#'+thisID,this).click(function() {
        var Allclassnames = $(this).parent();
        console.log(Allclassnames); 
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

Make sure that every element in frame doc. have some id or else the alert() may throw an error.

To see the console message of iframe you need to change the scope from the scope dropdown , it's in console tab besides the filter icon in the chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with the contents of an `iframe` unless it is on the same domain as the parent document.

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy